# Delete 'Specials Unicode' in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, unicode

Im having a hard time removing the rows in a Dataframe that contains this char �. I have tried  `df_one.loc[df_one['Time'].str.contains(r'[^\x00-\x7F]+') == False]`
But is not working.

Comment: Is the replacement character (that's its proper name) always at the beginning? Because a string like `'abc�'` also matches your regex.

Comment: Not always, that is the reason I was thinking in a .contains or something like that

Comment: Why don't you filter for rows that contain `"�"`?

Comment: this � isnt a normal char by so I dont know how to look for it in the rows, I dont know the way to look for it.

Comment: Please  [edit] your question to provide a [mcve]. How do you get `df_one`?  That `�` is a _replacement character_ so somewhere _beyond_ must be a valid one?

Comment: If you *see* replacement characters (in your terminal or whatever you use to run Python), but the underlying characters are something else, then it's most probably a misconfiguration of your terminal, but the data may be alright after all. You should first fix the viewing issue, so you actually know what you are dealing with.